# Gerrit branch deletion

Tags: git, branch, git-branch, gerrit

I used the Gerrit Web UI to create a branch in a project. Now I want to delete that branch, but do not see any "delete" button next to the branch in the Web UI. Can I delete the branch using the Git client? Or, will attempting to mix Gerrit and Git in branch creation and deletion cause problems for the repo?

Comment: Did you try the methods listed in the [documentation](https://gerrit-review.googlesource.com/Documentation/project-configuration.html)?

Comment: If this is a rhetorical question, yes I did do due diligence before posting. If you were just curious, no, but I had read the docs but wanted to clarify before I start messing with the repo.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't see the "DELETE" button in the Web UI, probably you don't have "Delete Reference" permission. See more info in the Gerrit documentation [here](https://gerrit-review.googlesource.com/Documentation/access-control.html#category_delete).

Answering your question: yes, you can delete a branch using the Git client but you also need to have permission on Gerrit and then execute:

```
git push origin :<branch>
```